# Bash error due to space in directory name

Tags: bash

I am getting a Bash error of "binary operator expected" or "too many arguments" and it points to this second line of code (the if statement). The error goes away if top_dir has no spaces. How can I fix this code if I am required to use a top_dir with a space?

```
log_dir="${top_dir}/${group}"
if [ ! -d $log_dir ]; then
    mkdir -p "${log_dir}"
fi
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ would have identified and reported your issue automatically.

Comment: Wow, shellcheck.net is a great resource. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `[ ... ]` you need quotes to prevent expansion:

```
if [ ! -d "$log_dir" ]; then
```

With `[[ ... ]]` you can omit quotes and expansion won't happen:

```
if [[ ! -d $log_dir ]]; then
```

Example:

```
$ x='a b'
$ mkdir "$x"

$ [ -d "$x" ] && echo "$x exists"
a b exists

$ [[ -d $x ]] && echo "$x exists"
a b exists
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `if`, from:

```
if [ ! -d $log_dir ]; then
```

to:

```
if [ ! -d "${log_dir}" ]; then
```

Comment: The curly braces are unnecessary here; it's only the quotes that matter.

Comment: That's true, yet using curly braces is a good habit. That's why I added it here too.